# GNU gettext msgfilter program says "invalid multibyte sequence"

Tags: locale, gettext

GNU gettext program msgfilter seems not to accept UTF8 string as a result of the script that is given as a filter. The script just returns a prepared text which is read from a file.

Here is the test setup:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
cat /tmp/t3.txt
' > /tmp/trans01.sh
chmod a+rwx /tmp/trans01.sh
```

Then there is a file /tmp/t3.txt:

```
cat /tmp/t3.txt
```

Result:

```
AMSTERDAM REISEFÜHRER FÜR REISE, UNTERKUNFT, SEHENSWÜRDIGKEITEN
```

It is utf-8 file:

```
file /tmp/t3.txt
```

Gives:

```
/tmp/t3.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Further:

```
echo 'msgid "kk71ams_amsterdam_main_page_title"
msgstr "AMSTERDAM TOURIST GUIDE FOR TRAVEL, ACCOMMODATION, ATTRACTIONS"
' > /tmp/te1.po
```

Than:

```
cat /tmp/te1.po
```

Gives:

```
msgid "kk71ams_amsterdam_main_page_title"
msgstr "AMSTERDAM TOURIST GUIDE FOR TRAVEL, ACCOMMODATION, ATTRACTIONS"
```

Than:

```
file /tmp/te1.po
```

Gives:

```
/tmp/te1.po: GNU gettext message catalogue, ASCII text
```

Locale:

```
:~# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Now the problem with 'msgfilter':

```
~# msgfilter -i /tmp/te1.po '/tmp/trans01.sh'
msgid "kk71ams_amsterdam_main_page_title"
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
/tmp/te1.po:2: invalid multibyte sequence
msgstr "AMSTERDAM REISEFHRER FR REISE, UNTERKUNFT, SEHENSWRDIGKEITEN\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same situation, but I had the same issue and I solved it by adding the correct Content-type.

I had:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ASCII\n"
```

This seesms to be the default.

And changed it to:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Even though my file was also UTF-8, I explicitly had to change the charset in the Content-Type

Comment: I'm facing the same problem (though I am more like trying to hack together a working makefile for this) and I am a bit confused by your answer. I know such strings only from situations where it's all about a file being served by a web server, could you please explain exactly where you changed that line to get gettext working with äöü and the like?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. My mistake was that I didn't know I should simply copy the `.pot` file instead of using some command and tried around with `touch de.po` and then using `msgmerge`, so the headers were missing. (Just copying is the correct way, right...?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just resolved it.

You may have forgot --keep-header in msgfilter command

this flags keep the header from the source file in the output file, if not done the output po file is considered as a ASCII file apparently.

now I do:
msgfilter --keep-header -i mvap.po -o en_US.po ./script_merge_translate.sh

and it works